# Python ZipFile and Suppress Creating Zip File if Directory is Empty

Tags: python, python-zipfile

Attempting to zip a directory for further file processing.  I am able to successfully zip and move the file as expected.  However, if the directory does not contain any files, the ZipFile process is still creating an empty ZipFile.  My requirements are to only create a zip file if there are files present in said directory.

Thanks in advance for any help and assistance!

```
# STEP 3 - Create ZipFile
zip_path = 'E:/GL/download_ceridian/ceridian.zip'
directory_to_zip =  'E:/GL/download_ceridian'

folder = pathlib.Path(directory_to_zip)
filelist = list(folder.iterdir())

with ZipFile(zip_path, 'w' , ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip:
    for file in filelist:
        zip.write(file , arcname=file.name)
```

Comment: move you `with....` inside an `if filelist:`

Comment: Thanks Jon...any chance you can provide sample syntax as to how to accomplish this?  Been trying different avenues with no luck.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You likely want to just guard for the times that there are no files:

```py
# STEP 3 - Create ZipFile
zip_path = 'E:/GL/download_ceridian/ceridian.zip'
directory_to_zip =  'E:/GL/download_ceridian'

folder = pathlib.Path(directory_to_zip)
filelist = list(folder.iterdir())

if filelist:
    # filelist is not an empty list...
    with ZipFile(zip_path, 'w' , ZIP_DEFLATED) as zip:
        for file in filelist:
            zip.write(file , arcname=file.name)
```